# Adding multimedia field in [Navigation] Keyword causes 404 item not found error in page

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

I have a multimedia field in the [image: Navigation Keyword]
When I publish the Navigation category, it is fine. I can see the image in the folder. But when we link this keyword to a page and publish this page then the page gives 404 item not found. If I leave the image field empty and publish, the page is found. I don't see any errors. Is this a bug in DXA?

Update: When I checked the model service logs it gave the below error.

> PageModelExpander - Cannot expand entity
>   EntityModelData(id=135529-126337, componentTemplate=null,
>   linkUrl=null, content=null, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null)
>   for page PageRequestDto(publicationId=10, uriType=tcm, path=/en,
>   includePages=INCLUDE, contentType=MODEL, dataModelType=R2,
>   expansionDepth=100,
>   depthCounter=com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.DepthCounter@9b)
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaItemNotFoundException: Cannot find
>   a CP for componentUri = tcm:10-135529, template id = 126337

Comment: Is the given Component (`tcm:10-135529`) published (as DCP)? It looks like you're using "dynamic expansion" for the Component Link (i.e. the Component's Schema is associated with the "Generate Data Presentation" DCT). Is that intentional?

Comment: @RickPannekoek, I haven't associated this component's schema with the "Generate Data Presentation" DCT. If I open this template (tcm:10-126337-32), I can see that it is only linked to Article Schema which is the default setting of DXA.